# PostGIS points along a line aren't actually falling on the line

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I have a line network and I am placing points at equal intervals along each line. These points will be used to cut the lines into segments. I have found a way to create the points along the lines:

```
CREATE TABLE split_pt as

WITH line AS 
    (SELECT
        id,
        geom 
    FROM line_table),
linemeasure AS
    (SELECT
        ST_AddMeasure(line.geom, 0, ST_Length(line.geom)) AS linem,
        generate_series(0, ST_Length(line.geom)::int, 160.9) AS i
    FROM line),
geometries AS (
    SELECT
        i,
        (ST_Dump(ST_GeometryN(ST_LocateAlong(linem, i), 1))).geom AS geom 
    FROM linemeasure)

SELECT
    row_number() over() as id,
    i,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)), 3857) AS geom
FROM geometries;
```

However, I have two problems:

1. I'm getting around 400 duplicate points
2. About 60% of the points are not actually on the line so running the subsequent ST_Split() with these points against the lines doesn't work in most instances.

I am looking for help to eliminate duplicate points and to ensure that the points I create in the above query will return True on ST_Intersects(). I'd like to be able to incorporate these two aspects in the the above query and not in subsequent steps, if possible.

Comment: could you add a simple input geometry and the result of the intermediate results

Comment: Due to the limitations of IEEE floating-point values, it might not be possible for a point to land exactly on a line.

Comment: Why don't you just segment the lines into the required segments?

Comment: @Cyril unfortunately segmentizing the lines also keeps all segments that are shorter than the specified length. My lines have quite a lot of vertices as-is (so already lots of short segments), and I do need to keep most of them, to retain the shape

Comment: and how does the ST_ClosestPoint() function behave - does it return "bad points" exactly on the line or not?

Comment: doubling point removal: DELETE from geometries WHERE NOT id IN( SELECT min(id) as idpnt from geometries group by geom);

Comment: and what about : https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineLocatePoint.html and his counter part https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html ? it should garantee position on the line and provide a easier workaround

Comment: @cyril ST_ClosestPoint() does not return most of the points exactly on the lines. In fact, it doesn't result in any more points intersecting the lines than the query I provided in the question. Thinking comment from Vince is the limitation.

Comment: @IanTurton can you expand on your comment?

Comment: It's a pity that this is actually the case, because users assume that the point should be exactly on the line, and that's a lie, it would still be a lie to understand what the concept of a line in postgis is - it's hair, it's nano hair, how thick the line is, etc., etc. ? I've seen the JGH answer, but it doesn't solve your problem...

Comment: @cyril yes I agree that the point should be on the line. My goal was to use those points to split the lines at those places. I found that if I buffer the points by a very small amount (0.0001 or so), I can split the lines as expected. But then have to delete the infinitesimally small line segments left over. Not ideal, but it seems to work for now.

Comment: PostGIS interpolates between vertices, it's functional minimal unit for most geometries (e.g. a line) is a point array, and trigonometry; floating point error is the issue here. [`ST_QuantizeCoordinates`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_QuantizeCoordinates.html) can help, but really you should be looking at [`ST_LineSubstring`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html).

Comment: @pdavis point buffering is like a workaround or hack, I think it's worth checking out the ThingumaBob. The ST_Split and ST_Difference behavioral functions are similar, it feels like they were developed by the same programmer and work well when the user is dealing with the same object, but become a headache when the number of objects increases...I think developers understand the problem and will try to solve it in the future...

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/192526/120129...

Comment: @ThingumaBob, ST_LineSubstring was I should have been looking at all along. If you'd like, please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Better look at using [`ST_LineSubstring`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html); no issues with coordinate precision, but somewhat tricky to set up...

---

***Edit:**
I then packed it into a more sophisticated [set of functions](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/st_linesubstringsbyvalue.sql) a while ago; there's a *C* function add-on as well, for those who like to build from source.*

I packed that functionality into a (naive) function a few years ago:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_LineSubstringByLength(

  geom       GEOMETRY(LINESTRING),
  length     FLOAT8,
  use_meter  BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE

) RETURNS SETOF geometry_dump AS

  $$
  DECLARE

    len_frac  FLOAT8;
    s_frac    FLOAT8;
    e_frac    FLOAT8;

  BEGIN

    IF ($3)
      THEN  len_frac := $2 / ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY);
      ELSE  len_frac := $2 / ST_Length(geom);
    END IF;

    FOR n IN 0..CEIL(1.0 / len_frac)
      LOOP
        s_frac := len_frac * n;
        IF (s_frac >= 1.0)
          THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        e_frac := len_frac * (n + 1);
        IF (e_frac > 1.0)
          THEN
            e_frac := 1.0;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEXT (ARRAY[n + 1], ST_LineSubstring($1, s_frac, e_frac));
      END LOOP;

    RETURN;

  END
  $$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

The function accepts:

- a **LineString** `GEOMETRY`
- a **Length** value by which the given LineString should be divided
  (until the last element which will be of the rest length)
- a **Switch** to set the given length to be interpreted as *meter*; defaults to `TRUE`
  (**input geometry needs to be in EPSG:4326; it really just casts to `GEOGAPHY` for the fraction calculation**)

The function returns a `SETOF geometry_dump` (a `RECORD` just like e.g. `ST_Dump`) having:

- a **path** value (`INTEGER[]`) indicating the position of the current row in the extraction starting from the beginning of the input LineString
- a **geom** member (`GEOMETRY`)

A record looks like:

```
({1}, 01020000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000A65F8237663FC13F0000000000000000)
({2}, 010200000002000000A65F8237663FC13F0000000000000000A65F8237663FD13F0000000000000000)
```

---

Usage:

```
SELECT * FROM ST_LineSubstringByLength('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 0)'::GEOMETRY, 15000);
SELECT * FROM ST_LineSubstringByLength('LINESTRING(0 0, 5 0)'::GEOMETRY, 1, FALSE);

SELECT id, (dmp).path[1], (dmp).geom
FROM   <table_with_geom_and_id_columns>,
       LATERAL ST_LineSubstringByLength(geom, <length_in_meter?>[, TRUE|FALSE]) AS dmp
;
```

Comment: It's trivial btw. to alter this function to accept an integer value of segments it should divide the input LineString into. I use a customized PostGIS version on my machine where I add all those things that I can directly into the C function base; it's trivial to have these functions then to return segments for any geometry (using e.g. the boundaries)...and it's about 10 to 100 times faster. if you don't mind building from source...?